# What is the cost of ContainsAll in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, list, interface

I discovered `containsAll()` (a `List` interface method) during some coding today, and it looks pretty slick.  Does anyone know how much this costs in terms of performance/iterations?

The [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/List.html#containsAll%28java.util.Collection%29) didn't offer much in terms of that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- first, it iterates each element of the supplied collection
- then it iterates all elements of the list and compares the current element with them using `.equals(..)` (Note: this is about lists, as you specified in the question. Other collections behave differently)

So it's O(n*m), where n and m are the sizes of both collections.

```
public boolean containsAll(Collection<?> c) {
    Iterator<?> e = c.iterator();
    while (e.hasNext())
        if (!contains(e.next()))
        return false;
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Your second bullet point assumes a generic implementation of `contains()`, but `HashSet`/`HashMap` do it in O(1), any sorted collection might do it in O(logn).

Comment: @PhilippReichart I'm aware of that, but the question refers to lists

Comment: Oh, right. My mind was drifting to the original definition of `Collection.containsAll()` that's overriden by `List.containsAll()`.

Comment: in fact, it's not. The snippet I copied is from AbstractCollection. I added a note about different collections (maps, sets)). But as he refers to lists, I'll retain the focus there

Comment: Blast, I suspected as much.  Thanks!  I'm glad you mentioned that HashMap has something similar -- I'll be looking into using that next time.

Comment: @Philipp Reichart so you are saying comparing two hashSets will have only O(1) time complexity in total?

Comment: HashSet.contains is O(1), but containsAll needs to check that for all elements, so containsAll cannot be faster than O(n) for a general HashSet.

Answer (score 6):

Use the source, Luke :)

Edit: As Bozho pointed out, you're asking about `List.containsAll()` which overrides `Collection.containsAll()`. The following ramblings are mainly concerned with the latter:

Most `Collection` classes will use the [implementation of `containsAll` from `AbstractCollection`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/java/util/AbstractCollection.java#AbstractCollection.containsAll%28java.util.Collection%29), which does it like this:

```
public boolean containsAll(Collection<?> c) {
    for (Object e : c)
        if (!contains(e))
            return false;
    return true;
}
```

There's no guarantee that some implementation does it completely differently, though -- which could result in either better or worse runtime behavior.

The above implementation of `containsAll` will be at least O(n) where n is the number of items in the *`Collection` parameter* you pass in, **plus** whatever time `contains` takes:

- For a `HashSet`/`HashMap` this might be O(1) (best case, no collisions), so the overall runtime of `containsAll` would still be O(n)
- For an `ArrayList`, `contains` will take O(m) where m is the number items in the list (not the parameter), so the overall time for `containsAll` would be O(n*m)

Comment: Um, that's the `addAll` implementation, not `containsAll`.  But OP: for most implementations, `containsAll` costs `O(n^2)`; it doesn't do anything especially cool.

Comment: @LouisWasserman Oops, copy-pasted the wrong blob of code. Fixed.

Comment: To clarify: that's for most `List` implementations.  `containsAll` generally takes `O(n)` times the cost of a `contains` query.

Answer (score 1):

if you are calling A.containsAll(B)

openjdk iterates all elements of B calling A.contains(b).

A.contains(b) iterates all elements of A calling a.equals(b)

This is taken from source for [open jdk 7](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/jdk7-gate/jdk/file/e947a98ea3c1/src/share/classes/java/util/AbstractCollection.java)

Comment: Specific Collection classes might override `contains()` to provide better implementations though. Think `HashSet`.

Comment: agreed. I didn't bother looking at every implementation of AbstractCollection.

Answer (score 0):

consider

n.ContainsAll(m)

the best possible case scenario is O(m), and that's if n is a perfect hash set.

considering unsorted lists, i can come up with an O(n*log(n) + m*log(m)) algorithm

Comment: What is the algorithm for that ?

Comment: @SumitKumarSaha  that's the time complexity for mergesort on both lists.  once you do that, you can just keep an iterator on each list and match the elements as you iterate through each.  you should only have to do it once for each list. O(m+n)