# Finding characters missing in one word

Tags: kotlin

This is a learning task, its essence is to use functions on collections, it should work in 1 line. When entering `abс acb ab` should output `c`, since c is missing in exactly one word. Literally , the task sounds like this:
"There are several words in a line separated by spaces (one space between words). What characters are missing in exactly one word?"

I only understand how to split words into letters, but I don't understand how to compare lists (in my case), that's what I've done so far (this code splits words into letters):

```
fun main() {
    val s = readLine()?.split(" ")?.associateWith { it.map { it } }.also { println(it) }
}
```

I'm sure I'm on the right track, if this is not the case, then offer your approach.

Comment: Your sample input of `abc, acb ab` includes a comma. Is that right?

Comment: No, it's wrong, I'll edit it now

Comment: What if the input is abc abd ab?

Comment: This is an example of input, when you enter abc acb ab should output C, since it is missing C in one word, another example: owners woners owner, should output s because it is not in one word(last)

Comment: I misunderstood your question, nothing should be output

Comment: But when entering: a b. Should output a b

Comment: Please read [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions). Specifically this part in the top answer: "Ask about specific problems with your existing implementation. If you can't do that yet, try some more of your own work first or searching for more general help; your professor is likely to be a better resource at this stage than Stack Overflow."

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Comparing two lists in kotlin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52054104/comparing-two-lists-in-kotlin)

Comment: How about `input.split(" ").map { it.toSet() }.run { maxBy { it.size } - minBy { it.size } }` - it may not be quite right for all inputs, but you can study it and change it accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Split the input string into words.
Create a list of all unique characters in those words.
Find the characters that occur exactly once.
Here's a one-liner that achieves this:

```
 fun main() {
        val s = readLine()?.split(" ")?.flatMap { it.toList() }
        val result = s?.groupingBy { it }.eachCount().filter { it.value == 1 }.keys
        println(result)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the final solution to this problem that I have come to

```
val s = readlnOrNull().let { it ->
  it?.takeIf { it.isNotEmpty() }?.let { s ->
     (0..255).map { c -> s.split(" ").count { w -> !w.contains(c.toChar()) } }
  }.also {
     it?.forEachIndexed { i, v -> if (v == 1) print(i.toChar()) }
     //println(it)
  }?.run { println() } ?: print("nothing has been entered")
```