# Which instance method is called when super type method calls method present in both super type and subtype

Tags: java, inheritance

Pardon me if I'm missing some core Java here.

I was searching through `HashSet`'s javadocs for the specification of it's implementation of `Collection.containsAll()` and it apparently inherits the implementation by `AbstractCollection` which according to the [JDK 8 source code documentation](https://github.com/frohoff/jdk8u-jdk/blob/master/src/share/classes/java/util/AbstractCollection.java) goes like this:

```
public boolean containsAll(Collection<?> c) {
    for (Object e : c)
        if (!contains(e))
            return false;
    return true;
}
```

My question stems from the fact that while `HashSet` does not override `containsAll()` it does however override `contains()`:

```
public boolean contains(Object o) {
    return map.containsKey(o);
}
```

`AbstractCollection` likewise:

```
public boolean contains(Object o) {
    Iterator<E> it = iterator();
    if (o==null) {
        while (it.hasNext())
            if (it.next()==null)
                return true;
    } else {
        while (it.hasNext())
            if (o.equals(it.next()))
                return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

My understanding has been that when an instance member call is not explicitly specified within the instance, the JVM implicitly replaces it with `this.instanceMemberCall()` which in this case would translate to `AbstractCollection`'s `contains()` being called. But then again [I read here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10199826/3864051) that the time complexity for `HashMap`/`HashSet`'s `containsAll()` would be O(n) suggesting that `HashSet`'s `contains()` (O(1)) is called. Would appreciate some clarity as to what the actual semantics behind this are.

Comment: @GhostCat Hit the nail on the head with the emphasis on the relevance of the runtime type :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, this is simply polymorphism. Whenever a method is invoked on an object, the *true* type of that object matters, nothing else.

Meaning: it doesn't matter that `foo()` is implemented in Base. When `foo()`calls `bar()` with `bar()` being overridden in Child. When you have a Child object, then it will always be the Child `bar()` version that gets called.

In your example, `this` isn't AbstractSet, it is `HashSet`!

Or again in other words: it doesn't matter "where" a method is invoked. What matters is the type of object it is invoked on. And as said, your object is of type HashSet!

Answer (score 2):

This is an interesting question. `HashSet` in Java is backed by `HashMap`. The `containsAll()` method is just looping over `contains()` in this case `HashSet`'s contains method. That's because `HashSet` overrides the `contains` and delegates.

Because `HashSet` is backed by the `HashMap` actual invocation is  `containsKey(Object key)`.

The `HashMap`'s `containsKey(Object key)` is mostly gives you `O(1)` complexity. However, the `containsAll()` does loop over `n` elements. Your worse case complexity become `O(n)`.

The reason I said it's ***mostly***, because performance of a `HashMap` relies on hashing.